# How to do mail merge in Gmail and/or Mac with attachments?

Tags: email, gmail, attachments, mail-merge

I need to send a template email to about 700 email addresses, and need to personalize each email for the recipient's name, position, and employer.  In addition, I have one attachment that I need to send to all recipients.  (This is for a research survey.)

I'm working on Mac OS 10.6 and don't have MS Outlook. Normally I use Gmail for all my accounts, but not sure how to do a mail merge with gmail.  Is there a way I can upload my list of recipients and associated fields to a Google Doc or Google Contacts, then create an email template that includes the attachment?

Are there any other solutions on the Mac that I could use?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with GMAIL and Google Docs, but I'd advise against it. Pumping out that many emails at once is gonna get you flagged as a **spammer**.  I suggest you find a email service like MailChimp and import your email list there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like like SalesHandy and Docsend allows document tracking and attachment tracking. SalesHandy is good option and allows other features like email tracking and email scheduling.